# how to make SetImagresource dynamic

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using a glide library to transform image path in my sqlite database to `imageview` in my `expendablelistview`..now I want to make those pictures to be zoomable so I used a photoview library ..the problem I got is that I can only choose one pictures to be displayed when calling `photoView.setImageRessource`. How can I adapt it to zoom every time different picture (depending on what is clicked from url)

This is my code:

```
case R.id.child3 :
    ImageView url = (ImageView) view;
    String urls;
    urls = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3));
    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(urls).into(url);
    url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, null);
            PhotoView photoView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anatomy);
            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **setImageDrawable()** instead,

```java
 url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, null);
                    PhotoView photoView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    photoView.setImageDrawable(((ImageView)view).getDrawable());
                    mBuilder.setView(mView);
                    AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
                    mDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ..yeah it did work ..but the image stays small..doesn't zoom